# Bootstrap col-md-3 div take relative height of last col-md-3 in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello web developers,
   I need help in bootstrap. I have divs of class col-md-3 in a row class. Total 4 col-md-3 in a row. But height of col-md-3 varies. It can be anything. Issue arises when height is not same. 
   So suppose 4 col-md-3 are appeared in a row and last col-md-3 is smaller or larger than others. Then 5th col-md-3 takes height of last col-md-3 and adjust as per it.You can view it at http://demo.wedevelopers.in/bootstraptest-54765/index.htm
  I want to 5th div to appear below first and so on. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance. Hope to hear good suggestions from you.

Comment: You could try using a jQuery plugin such as [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new row for your 5th `col-md`.

One `row` can accommodate `col-md-x`'s where the sum of x's is 12. It's a **12-grid system**. To clarify, sum of `col-md`'s in a row must be **12** or less.

Example:

```
<div class ="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="col-md-3">
</div>
<div class ="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="col-md-3">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I know this. 4 col-md-3 are equal to total col-md-12 which is maximum in row. But the next col-md-3 is appearing based on height of last col-md-3. But I need it in the respective columns.

Comment: Yeah, that's what. So try putting the 5th col-md in a separate row.

Comment: Ranveer is right but if you want them all appear at same height check out my answer :)

Comment: @user3745533 I think [Pinstrap](http://bragthemes.com/demo/pinstrap/) is what you're looking for. Haven't tried it myself although.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add .row after every 4 .col-md-3 ? Cuz you need to add a new .row if you want to go on next line . You said also that the height of divs vary , but if you want all of them to be equal add this to the css :

```
.col-md-3
{
  height:400px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Because If I add row then Everything will adjust based on maximum height of col-md-3. But I need to make it to adjust height based on the div which is above it. Height can be anything

Comment: Can you be more specific what you want then ?

Comment: More specifically I can say , If you view http://www.pinterest.com , Everything will adjust based on height of div above it. I need similar kind of it

Comment: All the divs on pinterest are with the same size and wifth , so if you adjust a div's height and width everything will be fine. And because you have different height divs , you can add overflow: scroll so you can scroll down to see more informatiuon